# How to create a sap fiori launchpad, not custom or config app to lanunchpad

Tags: sap-fiori

I'd like to create a sap fiori launchpad from scratch. What the should I do? For example, now I just have a develop system. I need a fiori launchpad. How to create it?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to SAP Fiori Crew's answer, make sure:

- Fiori Application is hosted
- oData Service hosted in the sap system same as UI Code with the RFC connection to the oData backend.

Use the above to create a tile and catalog.